# python django shell заменить на другой редактр

Tags: python, django

Начала изучать основы python django. Можно ли изменить встроенную оболочку shell для python django на другой редактор, например visual code?
Если запустить встроенную оболочку через команду `python.exe manage.py shell`, то с помощью нее могу получить список данных, например:

```
from bboard.models import Bb
for b in Bb.objects.all():
    if b.content == '':
        print(b.title)
```

Если я скопирую код и вставлю его в оболочку shell, то в ней игнорируются отступы, что вызывает ошибку,например

```
    >>> for b in Bb.objects.all():
    ... if b.content == '':
      File "<console>", line 2
        if b.content == '':
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Тем самым приходится копировать код построчно.

Имеется файл viewer.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Bb
from .models import Rubric

def by_rubric(request, rubric_id):
    bbs = Bb.objects.filter(rubric=rubric_id)
    rubrics = Rubric.objects.all()
    current_rubric = Rubric.objects.get(pk=rubric_id)
    context = {'bbs': bbs, 'rubrics': rubrics,'current_rubric': current_rubric}
    return render(request, 'bboard/by_rubric.html', context)

def index(request) :
    bbs = Bb.objects.all()
    rubrics = Rubric.objects.all()
    context = {'bbs': bbs, 'rubrics': rubrics}
    return render(request, 'bboard/index.html', context)
```

В дальнейшем функции будут объемнее и хотелось бы проверять работу некоторой части кода через visual code.
Например как выполнить код через редактр visual code?

```
from .models import Bb
from bboard.models import Bb

bbs = Bb.objects.all()
for b in bbs:
    if b.content == '':
        print(b.title)
```

Если я открываю и запускаю код через visual code, то получаю ошибку:

```
from .models import Bb
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

или

```
from bboard.models import Bb
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Answer (score 2):

Один рабочий вариант - это использовать ipython, который в отличии от стандартной оболочки поддерживает нормальную вставку, редактирование, поиск по истории и еще [кучу других плюшек](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html#enhanced-interactive-python-shell).

Для этого достаточно установить пакет ipython в виртуальное окружение и  `python.exe manage.py shell` автоматически его будет использовать.

```
IPython 7.27.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: def f():
   ...:     print('a')
   ...:

In [2]: f()
a

In [3]:
```